# Use PHP to list file names in a folder selected by the user

Tags: php, file, directory, scandir

I have tried the HTML5 webkitdirectory approach to upload all the files in a specified directory.

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple="" directory="" webkitdirectory="" />
```

However, I only want the list of file names in the directory selected by the user, instead of having the browser upload all the files to the server.

Basically, I want to apply the scandir() function on the client side. Is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: i don't think it's possible. It's possible using ActiveX object but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you're unable to apply scandir() on a client-side since PHP is executed on the server-side